# Query Entity with jdoDetachedState set to null

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

When I query entity in Google App Engine using JPA a field called `jdoDetachedState` is added auto to my object. I read that it has something with JPA Object Lifecycle.
for example:

```
{"id":216001,"m_Name":"x","jdoDetachedState":[{"key":216001,"targetClassName":"util.Profile","hashCode":1061531169,"keyAsObject":null},null,[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[]]}
```

The problem is that after deserializing (Using GSON) the Entity and accessing getName() I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList at util.Profile.jdoGetm_Name
```

jdoGetX is another thing among other that is auto added to my object.

I managed to fix it by adding:

```
@Transient   
protected Object[] jdoDetachedState;
```

to my Entity and set it to null.

My question is if I can query the entity with Detached State set to null in the first place ,in case that I don't have any purpose in the state lifecycle.

I tried:

```
EMF.get().createEntityManager().deatch(profile);
```

But it did'nt  work.

Comment: FYI : The standardised bytecode enhancement contract is well enough defined at http://db.apache.org/jdo/enhancement.html and is easily enough validated with a decent decompiler such as http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui

Comment: thanks I know about http://db.apache.org/jdo/enhancement.html and http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui pretty cool. But it is not get me forward. Any idea how to query only the origin fields?

Comment: no idea what you mean by "query". I see no JDO query in your post. I see some things about serialising and deserialising but no statement about what was there before and what was wrong after

Comment: When I create new profile jdoDetachedState is null then I presist it  to the datastore. when I calling em.createQuery("..") I get back my profile with jdoDetachedState as I wrote. I'm asking if I can get the profile from datastore without the extra parameter like jdoDetachedState or set to null

Comment: That field is always null, unless you detach the object, as per the bytecode enhancement contract.